# Rally API, Creating Test Case Result - Connection Closed Exception

Tags: java, rally

I'm developing in java / groovy and am new to the Rally API, I begun using it last week. I want to be able to use the REST API to create a new Test Case Result. On friday (its monday when I wrote this), I got it working using the example below, putting in the data I wanted using arguments into the method. I found this example on another website.

Today when I ran the code, and I dont think I changed anything, I keep getting "ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1390; received: 1389).

I rewrote the code again, this time not changing anything from the example just to try and get it working again, and I get the same exception. Heres the code I'm using:

```
public static void createTestCaseResults(){
        // Create and configure a new instance of RallyRestApi
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),"username@company.com", "Password");
        restApi.setWsapiVersion("1.36");
        restApi.setApplicationName("Add Test Case Result");

        //Query User
        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "username@company.com"));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();

        // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC7562"));
        QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
        JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString();

        try{
            //Add a Test Case Result
            System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
            JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2012-06-12T18:00:00.000Z");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Automated Selenium Test Runs");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2012.05.31.0020101");
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
            newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);

            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
            CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);

            if(createResponse.wasSuccessful()){
                println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));
                //Read Test Case
                String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                println(String.format("Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s", obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));
            } else {
                String[] createErrors;
                createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case: ");
                for (int i=0; i<createErrors.length;i++) {
                    System.out.println(createErrors[i]);
                }
            }

        }
        finally{
            restApi.close()
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help with this. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your code looks good.  I remember seeing a similar exception sporadically during the initial development of the java toolkit.  I'm going to look into it.  Out of curiosity what OS/JRE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Is this still happening for you today?  I just tried your code on both rally1 and our demo system, and it works reliably every time (only changed username and password, and the test case formatted id).

As a possible next step, I'd set a breakpoint in RallyRestApi.doRequest where the server response code is checked and see what additional information was available - for example, the response code, and the body and headers for the response.

Comment: in this code get("_ref").toString() has to be replaced with get("_ref").getAsString() per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405917/get-objectid-from-url-via-rest-api-java/18406182#18406182

Answer (score 1):

This very well may be a bug in the underlying Apache HttpComponents library.  I just upgraded to the latest 4.2.1 components.  Would you mind giving the new 1.0.2 jar a try?

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava

**Update:**
This has been fixed with the 1.0.4 release of the toolkit today:
https://github.com/downloads/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/rally-rest-api-1.0.4.jar