# Get ObjectID from URL via REST API Java

Tags: java, rally

I try to add Discussion to User Story. Part of code

```
        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
        JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();
        System.out.println("Ref: " + storyRef);

        Ref ref = new Ref();
        System.out.println(ref.getOidFromRef(storyRef));
        System.out.println(ref.isRef(storyRef));

        createDis.addProperty("Artifact", ref.getOidFromRef(storyRef));
        createDis.addProperty("Text", "Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java-Java");
        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("ConversationPost", createDis);
        CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);
```

System.out.println("Ref: " + storyRef) return
Ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/13097497257"

ref.getOidFromRef(storyRef) return NULL
ref.isRef(storyRef) return FALSE

Why???

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid and is causing your ref to have an extra set of quotes around it:

```
String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();
```

Changing it to this should get it to work correctly:

```
String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
```

Always use the getAs methods rather than toString.